# rails - decrement active record column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm having issues decrementing a column of one of my active records.

Getting the record like this -

```
@post = Post.active.find(params[:post_id])
```

It successfully returns the post.

Then calling `@post.decrement_likes_count` which lives in my post model.

decrement_likes_count:

```
def decrement_likes_count
  self.post_likes_count -= 1
  self.save!
end
```

It literally just does the save part and does not touch the `post_likes_count` column at all.

When I check the heroku logs, all it does it update the `updated_at` column of the post but doesn't decrement that counter.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what is the exact issue it's not saving the record but I would suggest to take a look at [**`decrement`**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/decrement) method provided by ActiveRecord.

Syntax:

```
decrement(attribute, by = 1)
```

e.g

```
@post = Post.active.find(params[:post_id])
@post.decrement(:post_likes_count)
@post.save
```

The good thing about this method is you don't need to worry about `nil` values. It handles them.